# How do I call 3rd party REST service from Dynamics 365 CRM online?

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, oauth, dynamics-crm

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155379/call-external-api-from-microsoft-dynamics-365-online) question is almost the same but I need to secure the call with an access token.

Therefore, when calling external web api from Dynamics 365 CRM online I need to set the Authorization request header with a Bearer token.

How do I get hold of the access token to send with the call?

**EDIT:** 
We are using Azure Ad to login to Dynamics 365 CRM online and at that moment we receive a token persisted in a cookie.

When we make a call to external web api we want to send that token with our call as an Authorization header.

**EDIT:**

We have tried to create a Plugin/Activity (C#) but there is no cookie collection (what we can see) in that context. In the example below we tried with clientid and clientcredentials but users information is not involved there.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;

namespace MyPlugin
{
    public class TestPlugin : IPlugin
    {
        private const string ClientId = "***";
        private const string ClientSecret = "***";
        private const string AadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
        private const string TenantId = "***";
        private const string PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://***.crm4.dynamics.com";

        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var tracer = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
            var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            var accessToken = GetTokenWithoutAdal().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            tracer.Trace(accessToken);

            RetrieveAccounts(accessToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetTokenWithoutAdal()
        {
            var loginUrl = AadInstance + $"{TenantId}/oauth2/token";

            var client = new HttpClient();
            var postData = $"client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&resource={PostLogoutRedirectUri}&grant_type=client_credentials";

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, loginUrl) { Content = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8) };

            request.Content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            request.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(request);

            var jsonResponseString = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            string something = null;
            //Do something

            return something;
        }

        private static async Task<string> RetrieveAccounts(string token)
        {
            var webApiUrl = "https://***.test.com/v1.0";
            var url = $"{webApiUrl}/accounts";

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            var jsonContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return jsonContent;
        }
    }
}
```

A workmate has also tried using Javascript in calling a LogicApp, but no token is sent.

```
function callLogicApp() {
    fetch('https://dynamicstestapi.azure-api.net/manual/paths/invoke',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    title: 'foo',
                    body: 'bar',
                    userId: 1
                }),
                credentials: 'include',
                mode: 'cors',
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'e1e884bbe9a945a9a4dbcabff49e59d8'
                }
            })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(console.log);
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is what I want, users access token (only payload from JWT)

```
{
  "aud": "https://myapi.net",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/******-****-4c1e-b346-2a28ef579dea/",
  "iat": 1567158525,
  "nbf": 1567158525,
  "exp": 1567162425,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "ASQA2/8MAAAA1czfs/LOnB0mRwLY****ZF4tHvcoN+oOwpFUE1F6cgU=",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "appid": "6792c685-bbf7-****-b15f-7b047edd2db6",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "family_name": "Lastname",
  "given_name": "Firstname",
  "ipaddr": "194.114.***.***",
  "name": "Firstname Lastname",
  "oid": "0ba39690-fb32-****-8d6c-3e4826b2f05b",
  "puid": "10030000826E****",
  "scp": "Directory.Read.All User.Read",
  "sub": "3C04Virz0afCxbAfY5****YfNgnC9HR7y3Mqcbgu5wg",
  "tenant_region_scope": "EU",
  "tid": "6f310cfb-5ece-****-b346-2a28ef579dea",
  "unique_name": "fname.lname@domain.com",
  "upn": "fname.lname@domain.com",
  "uti": "U9v1VNGnY0i****-wHlCAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

This is what I can get with clientid and clientsecret (only payload from JWT)

```
{
  "aud": "https://myapi.net",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/******-****-4c1e-b346-2a28ef579dea/",
  "iat": 1567161484,
  "nbf": 1567161484,
  "exp": 1567165384,
  "aio": "42FgYKhpmv0+****3SV/FZvuDbduAA==",
  "appid": "3401bb09-a6f2-****-846a-ef4570b3a8bd",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/******-****-4c1e-b346-2a28ef579dea/",
  "oid": "125746e6-4f03-****-8cf9-d568b9fce035",
  "sub": "125746e6-4f03-****-8cf9-d568b9fce035",
  "tid": "6f310cfb-5ece-****-b346-2a28ef579dea",
  "uti": "QiEIwm3560-****ZLz4RAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: *How do I get hold of the access token to send with the call?* What access token?

Comment: How does this question relate to Azure?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, I have edited my question, does that help?

Comment: Can you show what you have got so far?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, I included what we have been looking into.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, am I still unclear of what my question is?

Comment: Generally when calling an external API you would use some sort of static credentials (i.e. client ID and secret) which are either hardcoded, or stored in the database and retrieved by the plugin. You can then leverage some existing framework like RestSharp to build a request with an authentication header. Can you explain how your CRM Login credentials are related to this API call?

Comment: @ZachMast My client wants to make sure it is the loggedin user that is making the call to api and use that information further on.

Comment: You have no context within a plugin to retrieve any sort of client side information such as AD authentication credentials or cookies.  You do have the ID of the executing system user, and you could build a header which includes this ID for authentication purposes.

Comment: @ZackMast, Thanks for your confirmation of that. Is it possible to do it with Javascript in the browser? Or is it any other soltion for this? Or should we then go for clientid and clientsecret?

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that my client actually want a mix of authentication/autorization and tracing.

We also got it confirmed from Microsoft that it is not possible to retrieve the users access token in D365 online and send it along with the call to the 3rd party rest service.